# Why do some elements of the joomla site not load after setting limit_req?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, rate-limiting, joomla

I have an Nginx reverse proxy that forwards http and https requests to contianers from a Docker server. Recently, I set up a DoS / DDoS protection on the proxy so that the docker server resources don't get saturated. The setup successfully mitigated the attacks, however some elements of the joomla site do not load. I wonder what I'm doing wrong. Below are the settings made.

Zone:

```
 # Limits
 limit_req_log_level    warn;
 limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=rateLimiting:1m rate=10r/s;
```

Config reverse proxy:

```
 # reverse proxy for joomla container
    location / {
        limit_req zone=rateLimiting burst=20 nodelay;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.88.10:8082;
    }
```

Additional Information:

Nginx version: 1.14.2

Reference:

https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to adjust the numbers. I'd open networking tools in a browser and compare the request count to the server limits. You want to have all your requests served, right? Possibly the unserved requests are logged on the server. Possibly this can be turned on in some debugging mode. So you might take it from there as well. Or from both sides.